# Приложение работает на виртуальном устройстве, но падает на физическом

Tags: android, textview, drawable

Проблема следующая: есть `ViewHolder`, в нем есть `private val rating: TextView`, в методе `bind()` в зависимости от данных этому `TextView` ставится `background`.

```
            rating.text = String.format("%.1f", this.movie.voteAverage).also {
                val background: Drawable? = when {
                    it.toDouble() >= 7.0 -> {
                        ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(itemView.resources, R.drawable.oval_green, null)
//                        ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.oval_green)
                    }

                    it.toDouble() >= 5.0 && it.toDouble() < 7.0 -> {
                        ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(itemView.resources, R.drawable.oval_yellow, null)
//                        ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.oval_yellow)
                    }
                    it.toDouble() < 5.0 -> {
                        ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(itemView.resources, R.drawable.oval_red, null)
//                        ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.oval_red)
                    }
                    else -> {
                        null
                    }
                }
                rating.background = background
            }
```

На виртуальном устройстве Nexus 5X API24 все прекрасно работает, `background` устанавливается, но на физическом устройстве приложение падает. Без установки `background`а, на физическом устройстве все работает.
Тестировал на Honor 6c и Samsung Galaxy J5 Prime.

**UPD**

Лог с Honor c6

```
08-15 17:26:11.478 5026-5026/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-15 17:26:11.554 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies-2/lib/arm64
08-15 17:26:11.668 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
08-15 17:26:11.702 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
08-15 17:26:11.702 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
08-15 17:26:11.994 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.drawable.Drawable com.google.android.material.progressindicator.ProgressIndicator.getCurrentDrawable() would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ProgressBar
08-15 17:26:12.037 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies I/LoginFragmentViewModel: com.voak.android.tmdbmovies.ui.login.LoginFragmentViewModel@2845bed
08-15 17:26:12.051 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
08-15 17:26:12.117 5026-5050/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 710c145, Iebe23be877
    Build Date                       : 08/23/16
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.08.00.00
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
08-15 17:26:12.123 5026-5050/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-15 17:26:12.139 5026-5050/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies W/OpenGLRenderer: load: so=/system/lib64/libhwuibp.so
    dlopen failed: library "/system/lib64/libhwuibp.so" not found
08-15 17:26:12.140 5026-5050/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies W/OpenGLRenderer: Initialize Binary Program Cache: Load Failed
08-15 17:26:32.910 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
08-15 17:26:37.733 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
08-15 17:26:37.753 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-15 17:26:37.753 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-15 17:26:50.931 5026-5115/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
08-15 17:26:51.009 5026-5115/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
08-15 17:26:52.136 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies I/LoginFragmentViewModel: SessionId: f3a500c18b64bd864acdf3ca2214c76312add0f0
08-15 17:26:52.456 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies I/HomeViewModel: com.voak.android.tmdbmovies.ui.bottomnavigation.home.HomeViewModel@1c65791
08-15 17:26:52.775 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-15 17:26:52.776 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-15 17:26:52.776 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-15 17:26:52.776 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-15 17:26:52.776 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-15 17:26:52.776 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-15 17:26:52.776 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-15 17:26:52.776 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-15 17:26:52.925 5026-5126/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
08-15 17:26:52.942 5026-5026/com.voak.android.tmdbmovies I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5026 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Покажите логи ошибки

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил

Comment: Это не похоже на лог ошибки. Или у вас какая-то очень редкая ошибка. Возможно что-то не то с картинками вашими или с тем, как вы их программно получаете. `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(itemView.resources, R.drawable.oval_green, null)` - такое впервые вижу за годы практики. Возможно в этом и проблема. Попробуйте более простой способ: `rating.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval_yellow)`. Если не поможет - попробуйте заменить картинку - может в ней проблема.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб `rating.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval_yellow)` не помогло. Приложение падает вообще без ошибки, просто как будто сворачивается. Не думаю, что проблема в картинке, если устанавливать ее в xml разметке, то все работает.

Comment: Крайне странно. То что вы пытаетесь сделать - рядовая задача, в которой почти нечему ломаться. У вас точно нет лога ошибки? Может вы не знаете как его искать? То что работает в разметке - не значит, что с картинкой всё ОК. Пока нет логов - остаётся только на картинку и грешить. Если, конечно, вы не делаете чего-то странного в коде, который не показываете. Ну и попробуйте ещё `.also {}` убрать - он тут явно лишний.

Comment: Может быть ещё тут проблема `String.format("%.1f", this.movie.voteAverage)` - вы точно уверены, что это работает? Т.е. если убрать код с картинками - оно будет работать, перестанет падать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Действительно, `.also { }` был лишним, видимо я неправильно понял, как он работает. Сделал через `rating.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval_yellow)` все заработало. Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за помощь @ЮрийСПб

```
            rating.text = String.format("%.1f", this.tvShow.voteAverage)
            when {
                this.tvShow.voteAverage >= 7.0 -> {
                    rating.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval_green)
                }

                this.tvShow.voteAverage >= 5.0 && this.tvShow.voteAverage < 7.0 -> {
                    rating.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval_yellow)
                }
                this.tvShow.voteAverage < 5.0 -> {
                    rating.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval_yellow)
                }
            }
```